# Blueimp jQuery File Upload - trouble changing var url

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I've got the plug in working unless I change the window.location url as suggested in the commented code - and as I would prefer to do.

Changing either one or both blueimp.github.com or blueimp.github.io to the desired domain lets the progress bar run and suggests success, but nothing ever uploads.

I'm changing them to a valid url of the site and server that's running it using blueimp, yet it fails.

Starting with this:

```
// Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
    var url = (window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.com' ||
                window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.io') ?
                '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/' : 'server/php/';
```

and changing to this:

```
// Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
    var url = (window.location.hostname === 'otherdomain.com' ||
                window.location.hostname === 'otherdomain.com') ?
                '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/' : 'server/php/';
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Sorry but is this 'otherdomain.com' your domain or what?

Comment: How would you do this for a MVC app?  referring to a controller?  for exmaple,    http://localhost:55767/Home/Upload

Answer (score 0):

change in main.js:

url: 'you_server'

Answer (score 0):

According to your case (as well as mine). You need to change the blueimp server into your own url. From the code given. You need to replace **otherdomain.com** with your domain name. And change **server/php** to where your **UploadHandler.php** is. But leave **//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/** untouched.

Comment: Why leave //jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/ untouched?

Answer (score -1):

Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler to solve the issue:

```
var url = (window.location.hostname === 'yourdomain' ||
    window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.io') ?
    '//yourpages.php/' : 'folderinsidethesever';`
```